# Webform submit button does not work

Tags: webforms

I have created a webform block. After I enter all the info in the webform, I clicked the Submit button. Nothing happens. Do you know why the Submmit button is not working?

This webform block's submit button works: http://godrupal.info/?q=contact-us

Actual webform node's submit button works : http://godrupal.info/?q=node/16. Then I created block of the node/16 but then this webform blocks's submit button does not work: http://godrupal.info/?q=plan-an-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look into your console log you will see the following errors

[image]

this happens when you hide a required field.

I had a look at your markup and found that you have the above 4 fields display set as none; and at the same time also has attribute required.

So remove the required attribute or apply novalidate on submitting form.

Comment: Thank you. After i display the fields, submit button is working. I did make the address field not required. I still have the same issue. I do need to hide the fields. I did look at the form settings of the webform and i did not see where to select no validate on submitting form?

Comment: Can you remove the required attribute from the hided field?

Comment: <form action="" novalidate> like this.

Comment: I did make the address date field not required now. It is working. I cant make the month/day/year not required bc I used date field. But the problem is that people can submit the form without entering the date. Option1- I can make the field required and display all fields Option2- I can make the field not required then hide the fields then I dont know where to enter form action = "" novalidate. Is it need to be entered in tpl file? I am still new. My two requirements: date must be required and     month/day/year field must be hidden.

Comment: try this in your template.php 
function THEMENAME_preprocess_webform_datefieldname(&$variables) {
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['novalidate'] = TRUE;
}

Comment: alternatively, remove html5 required attribute and add custom php or js validation. that would work best